# How does Google crawler find pages that are not linked to?

Tags: google, google-search, googlebot

Will Google crawler find a page that is not linked to? I.e. pages accessible by manually modifying the URL, like `http://www.example.com/node/1/[secret keyword]`. Note that it is only secret in that there are no links to it; this "secret" path should't hold sensitive information.

Answer (score 2):

If it isn't linked to, then it won't be found... But links could exist anywhere that you aren't even aware of internally so chances are, unless you really try hard and do some serious digging into the code, markup and output of your website, the likes of Google will find some route to it.

Why create a page that can't be found? There are other solutions if you just don't want it indexed or available to user groups.

Comment: In my case, appending to the path is as easy as adding a variable in my routes. Other solution I am aware of would be editing my robots.txt file. "No links" way seems much simpler. @Geoff